# Constrained Least Squares with Numpy and Python only

Tags: python, numpy, mathematical-optimization, numba, least-squares

How to do constrained Least Squares only using `numpy`. Is there any way to incorporate constraints into `numpy.linalg.lstsq()` or is there any `numpy`+Python workaround to do constrained Least Squares? I know that I can do this easily with `cvxpy` and `scipy.optimize`, but this optimization will be a part of `numba` JITed function, and those two are not supported by `numba`.

EDIT:
Here is a dummy example of a problem I want to solve

```
arr_true = np.vstack([np.random.normal(0.3, 2, size=20),
                      np.random.normal(1.4, 2, size=20),
                      np.random.normal(4.2, 2, size=20)]).transpose()
x_true = np.array([0.3, 0.35, 0.35])
y = arr_true @ x_true

def problem():
    noisy_arr = np.vstack([np.random.normal(0.3, 2, size=20),
                        np.random.normal(1.4, 2, size=20),
                        np.random.normal(4.2, 2, size=20)]).transpose()

    x = cvxpy.Variable(3)
    objective = cvxpy.Minimize(cvxpy.sum_squares(noisy_arr @ x - y))
    constraints = [0 <= x, x <= 1, cvxpy.sum(x) == 1]
    prob = cvxpy.Problem(objective, constraints)
    result = prob.solve()
    output = prob.value
    args = x.value

    return output, args
```

Essentially, my problem is to minimize $Ax-y$ subject to $x_1+x_2+x_3 = 1$ and $\forall x_i, 0 \leq x_i \leq 1$.

Comment: Can you provide an example and or explain what is the type of constraints you have?

Comment: I don't know if you can JIT `np.linalg.lstsq`, can you?

Comment: At the very least, you should be able to write your constraints as a penalty or merit function, and sum it with the original objective function. Have you defined the KKT conditions for your problem? If so, solve that system in order to get a solution for your problem. You could also try QR-factorization or Lagrange multipliers (least norm problem). It really depends on your specific problem. Are you looking for a solution, or a specific method to find the solution?

Comment: Please should your work / what you have tried.   Please also read [ask].

Comment: @jared you can JIT both `np.linalg.lstsq` and `np.linalg.solve` numba

Answer (score 3):

Is it linear? Based on your `numpy.linalg.lstsq` suggestion I'll assume that for now. Also, I assume (to solve the simple case first) that you talk about equality constraints. Then you can easily solve it yourself by using Lagrange multipliers, and the solution can be found by solving a linear equation system.

If the problem is to minimize `A * x - y` over the constraints `B * x = b`, then solve

[image]

As an example:

```
from numpy import array, zeros
from numpy.linalg import solve

A = array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])
y = array([3.2, 6.8, 11.1, 15.2])

B = array([[1, -1]])
b = array([0.1])

S = zeros((3, 3))
r = zeros(3)

S[:2, :2] = A.T @ A
S[2:, :2] = B
S[:2, 2:] = B.T
r[:2] = A.T @ y
r[2] = b

x = solve(S, r)[:2]
print(x)
```

Disclamer: Bugs might be included, but brief testing gave me for `x`

```
[1.06262376 0.96262376]
```

This seems reasonable, and my constraint x1 - x2 = 0.1 is also fulfilled.

Comment: thanks, this is great! i've updated the question with an example, please take a look. two questions: 1) what to do when you have inequality constraints, and 2) can you explain or point me to a resource about how you set up this Lagrange system in matrix form?

Comment: Sorry, @cc88, while I had the case of equality constraints in my head, I never seriously coded handling of inequality constraints myself. Also for the second question, look for multivariable optimization with Lagrange multipliers. This is really an optimization (minimization) of `(A*x - y)**2`.